# Conditional statement for null check

Tags: java

i have one conditional statement as below

```
if (Sizeval != null) {
            query.addFilterQuery("size:" + Sizeval);
        }
```

In debug i can see value of **Sizeval = null**

I am getting this value from a request object as below

```
Sizeval = (String) request.getParameter("Attr");
```

But even though Sizeval is null its executing the query.addFilterQuery statment.

Any suggestion to rectify this issue plz

Comment: each time Sizeval == ,null, that addFilterQuery will not be called. apparently, it's called (at least once) with Sizeval != null

Comment: So are you saying there is a bug in JVM ?

Comment: Can you share more code please? Do we have any code block between `request.getParameter` and `null` check?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ OBVIOUSLY :D

Comment: maybe it has the value `"null"` and you get tricked when viewing it in the debugger

Comment: There are no bugs in the JVM (at least this trivial). Apparently `Sizeval` is _not_ null. Try printing out Sizeval inside the if. I think the string contains the text "null" :)

Comment: If you are adding the parameter Attr to Sizeval then how can it's value be null??

Comment: Also, `getParameter` already returns a `String`... https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)

Comment: its not having string "null" because i am not moving anything to it in between.. and when i print the string its showing me null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rephrase your question. Given

```
HttpServletRequest requst = ...
String Sizeval = (String) request.getParameter("Attr");
if (Sizeval != null) {
    query.addFilterQuery("size:" + Sizeval);
}
```

you see that the body of the `if` is executed (implies `Sizeval` not null) but still `Sizeval` *seems* to be null (as observed in the debugger or in the constructed filter).

Explanation: `Sizeval` is not null but has the literal value `"null"`. This will add a `"size:null"` filter query. Also when the variable is viewed in a log or debugger it will seem to be `null`.

To verify do

```
if (Sizeval != null) {
    if ("null".equals(Sizeval))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("got it");
    query.addFilterQuery("size:" + Sizeval);
}
```

Comment: request.getParameter("Attr") is returning string 'null' rather than null object.. but in my JSP as a parameter i am passing null object itself.. I changed my logic. But didn't understood this behavior..

Comment: Can you show your JSP to explain how you pass null object parameter?

Answer (score 1):

`request.getParameter("Attr");` returns null, but you are casting the value to `String`.

When you check `if (Sizeval != null)` `Sizeval` has the value "null" instead of being `null` object.

`request.getParameter` already returns `String` or `null`, so just drop the casting.

Comment: how can i check whether the request parameters Attr value is null or not in that case plz..

Comment: @AVINASH I answered that, `request.getParameter` already returns `String` or `null`, so just drop the casting.

Comment: "Sizeval has the value "null" instead of being null object." -- WHAT?

Comment: how can i verify this?

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% but:

If 'request.getParameter("Attr")' returns null, and you cast it to a String, isn't this turned into String 'null'?

Got this problem before.

Comment: In that case how can check whether i got actual null or not?

Comment: Don't cast it to a string, but let it be of the same object. Or do a null check on the result before casting it to a string.

Comment: I tried all the comments even this is not working form me if(request.getParameter("Attr") != null).

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker no, casting a null object to String doesn't make it non-null.